# how to add dynamic view controller in caps page menu in ios

Tags: ios

how to add dynamic view controller in caps page menu in ios 
i get data in web services........,
controllerArray is not fixed.....,
I am using PageMenu to acomplish this result. The data is fetcehd from a web API. I want to dynamically create view controllers based on the number of days that the web API responds with so that each day can have a view controller so that it can display schedule for that day. How can I accomplish this?

```
 prcatViewController *noti1=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"prcatViewController"];
noti1.title=@"Category";

brand_view *noti2=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"brand_view"];
noti2.title=@"Brand";
color *noti3=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"color"];
noti3.title=@"Color";
size_view *noti4=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"size_view"];
noti4.title=@"Size";
price_ViewController *noti5=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"price_ViewController"];
noti5.title=@"Price";
noti6...,noti7......

NSArray *controllerArray = @[noti1, noti2, noti3, noti4,noti5,noti6,noti........];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{

                             CAPSPageMenuOptionScrollMenuBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor],

                             CAPSPageMenuOptionViewBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor],

                             CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectionIndicatorColor: [UIColor clearColor],

                             CAPSPageMenuOptionBottomMenuHairlineColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:70.0/255.0 green:70.0/255.0 blue:70.0/255.0 alpha:0.0],

                             CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectedMenuItemLabelColor :[UIColor greenColor],
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionUnselectedMenuItemLabelColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor],

                             CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15.0],

                             CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuHeight: @(40.0),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemWidth: @(90.0),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionCenterMenuItems: @(YES),

                             };

_pageMenu = [[CAPSPageMenu alloc] initWithViewControllers:controllerArray frame:CGRectMake(0.0, 68.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) options:parameters];
[self.view addSubview:_pageMenu.view];
```